# Are Indexes meaningful on Views?

Tags: postgresql

Is there any point in adding an index to a (non materialized) view?  I'm using Postgres, but I guess the question applies to SQL in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, non materialized views basically rely on their underlying queries both for the result set and with regard to performance.  So, to index a view, you should simply look at indexing the underlying query contained within the view.

Comment: Ofcourse! Should have asked to begin with -- but indexes _are_ useful for materialized views? I guess that refreshing the view also reindexes?

Comment: @user17038201 A materialized view is, in most database scenarios, closer to an actual table than a view.  If the RDBMS supports indexing materialized views, then yes it can help.